# Confusing mysql select results with LIKE and multiple zeros (%00%)

Tags: mysql

I have created a search query to search a table for a string in multple fields. It works for every string except if the string contains only one or multiple zeros eg: %000% returns rows with 2 or less zeros.

The search fields:

```
`par_partno` varchar(20) utf8_general_ci
`par_group_id` varchar(16) utf8_bin
`par_desc` text utf8_general_ci
`par_details` text utf8_general_ci
```

I already tried to cast `par_partno` to char `CAST(par_partno AS CHAR)` but the result is the same.

The query:

```
select `par_id`, `pag_id`, `par_partno`, `par_group_id`,`par_cond`, `par_desc`,`par_price`,
`par_stock`, `par_feature`, `par_weight`, `par_details`, `par_related`, `par_meta`,
`par_picture`, `par_lastmod`
from `parts`
where concat(`par_partno`, `par_group_id`, `par_desc`, `par_details`) like "%000%"
order by `par_group_id` asc
```

Wrong results:

```
[
{"par_id":"145100","pag_id":"1","par_partno":"7101263500","par_group_id":"01-00-12","par_cond":"New","par_desc":"Pedal Assy W\/ Booster Mbc, Clutch Cylinder","par_price":"1450.00","par_stock":"1","par_feature":"0","par_weight":"0.1","par_details":"","par_related":null,"par_meta":null,"par_picture":"0","par_lastmod":"2019-01-04 18:14:12"}, 
{"par_id":"145106","pag_id":"2","par_partno":"7121051100","par_group_id":"01-01-102","par_cond":"New","par_desc":"Seal Intake Valve","par_price":"5.95","par_stock":"1","par_feature":"0","par_weight":"0.1","par_details":"","par_related":"[\"7121040061\"]","par_meta":null,"par_picture":"0","par_lastmod":"2019-01-04 18:14:12"}, 
{"par_id":"145169","pag_id":"2","par_partno":"7122015100","par_group_id":"01-01-91","par_cond":"New","par_desc":"Engine Gasket Set","par_price":"199.00","par_stock":"1","par_feature":"0","par_weight":"6.4","par_details":"","par_related":null,"par_meta":null,"par_picture":"0","par_lastmod":"2019-01-04 18:14:12"}
]
```

Comment: All those rows have 3 zeros in the concat, 2 at the end of `par_partno` and one at the start of `par_group_id`

Comment: You're doing at least three confusing things: 1) Look for lowercase zeros :-? 2) Concatenate 3) Filter with `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`. None of these have an obvious purpose. Perhaps you should edit the question and explain your exact needs.

Comment: You're right, having is not necessary, its legacy code i had to edit. The lowercase has its purpose but is not relevant for the question. concat was the issue with the whole query. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## An improvement to [Robin's reference answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54124598/3536236):

*(too big / codey for comments)*

Run only one `LIKE` query, by combining the searched columns into one CONCATenation.

```
HAVING CONCAT_WS('-',par_partno,par_group_id,par_descpar_details) LIKE "%000%"
```

This function combines all checked columns into one string and seperates them with a `-` (any value that is not part of the `LIKE`).

This also removes the `LOWER()` function as it's needless when working with digits.

Comment: @Robin many thanks, I wasn't expecting this to be ticked! Cheers! `:-D`

Answer (score 2):

I might be missunderstanding your question, but isn't the checked string a concatenation of e.g.

> par_partno":"7101263500","par_group_id":"01-00-12"

so

> 710126350001-00-12

which contains a "000" substring.

Comment: Thats right, i should not have used concat in this query.

Answer (score 0):

The hints helped me to resolve this problem.

I removed the concat and replaced it with:

```
WHERE LOWER(par_partno) LIKE "%000%" OR LOWER(par_group_id) LIKE "%000%" 
OR LOWER(par_desc) LIKE "%000%" OR LOWER(par_details) LIKE "%000%"
```